# Does Apiary.io throttle responses?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I have an angularjs app that calls a RESTful service at apiary.io

Does apiary.io throttle responses and delay responses after a certain number have been received?

If so what are the parameters?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

From their [docs](http://docs.corepro.apiary.io/):

> API Call Limit
>
> API calls are subject to the default limit of 15 requests per second and exceeding this limit will result in all endpoints returning an HTTP status code of 429. Limits are per API key. If the limit is exceeding then the API Key will be blocked for the remainder of the sample period. If an API key continually hits the call limit we reserve the right to permanently block the key and to charge a fee to unblock the key.
>
> To determine the API call amount we monitor the traffic over a sample period. If the traffic results in a particular API key reaching 80% of the limit (i.e., 12 if the limit is 15) over the sample period then the responses will start to contain a throttle node which contains useful information on how close you are to reaching the call limit.

Answer (score 8):

Currently, Apiary limits you for 120 reqs/minute/IP.

There are no artificial delays, but occasionally someones floods Apiary with production traffic and even when ratelimiting is fairly efficient, it may temporarily degrade service for other users.

You can (and should) check `X-Apiary-RateLimit-Limit` and `X-Apiary-RateLimit-Remaining` header. Once you'll hit the limit, Apiary will sent `Retry-After` header you should obey.